# Fluxible Context methods hang

Tags: javascript, fluxible

I'm facing a situation where the methods in Fluxible Action context seem to hang. I think my trouble stems from the fact that I'm writing in ES5 and I've had to take my best guess at how the ES6 examples on Fluxible's homepage translate ([link](http://fluxible.io/addons/BaseStore.html) and [link](http://fluxible.io/api/fluxible.html)).

Anyway, here's some relevant code (simplified greatly to try and emphasize the parts that I think might be important):

**Store.js**

```
var BaseStore = require('fluxible/addons/BaseStore');
var assign = require('object-assign');

var Store = assign({}, BaseStore.prototype, {
    handleAction: function(data) {
       console.log('Action Done');
       this.emitChange();
    }
    ... (other methods) ...
}

Store.storeName = 'Store';
Store.handlers = { 'ACTION_DONE': 'handleAction' };

module.exports = Store;
```

**Actions.js**

```
var Promise = require('promise');
var Store = require('./Store');

var Actions = {
   action1: function(context, payload) {
       return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
           console.log('Action 1');
           context.dispatch('ACTION_DONE', {});
           resolve(true);
       });
   },

   action2: function(context, payload) {
       return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
           // Try to fetch a value from the store and display it
           var store = context.getStore(Store.constructor);
           console.log(store.getValue());
           context.dispatch('ACTION_DONE', {});
           resolve(true);
       });
   }
}

module.exports = Actions;
```

And I'm using this whole setup with the following lines

```
var Promise = require('promise');
var Fluxible = require('fluxible');
var Store = require('./Store');
var Actions = require('./Actions');

var app = new Fluxible();
app.registerStore(Store.constructor);

var context = app.createContext();
var action1 = context.executeAction(Actions.action1, {});
var action2 = context.executeAction(Actions.action2, {});

Promise.all([action1, action2]).then(function(val) { console.log('done'); });
```

I have found while debugging with print statements that execution gets stuck at `context.dispatch('ACTION_DONE', {});` in `Actions.action1` and at `var store = context.getStore(Store.constructor);` in `Actions.action2`. This makes me wonder at my ES5 translation of the examples - particularly my implementation of Store.js.

Any help would be appreciated. And do let me know if there is more information that I can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the method `createStore` in `fluxible/addons` could solve my problem - change the `assign({}, BaseStore.prototype, { ... })` to `createStore({ ... })`

I don't fully understand what the difference between what I'm doing now vs. what I was doing is; so feel free to respond with explanations. For now, my problem is solved.